# Cannot create jar file to upload on AWS Device Farm

Tags: testing, intellij-idea, automation, appium, aws-device-farm

I am using Appium test automation framework and i want to upload it on AWS Device Farm. I have updated the pom.xml and zip.xml file. When i run the command 'mvn clean package –-DskipTests=true' i get the following error.

```
    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building 1 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.109 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-07-25T14:54:43+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/77M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Unknown lifecycle phase "?-DskipTests=true". You must specify a valid li
fecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id
>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are
: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, p
rocess-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-
sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-
test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-
test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-cle
an, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
```

Can any one please give me a solution on this?? Previously i was getting mvn is not recognized as an internal or external command, so I installed maven separately.. Please help

Comment: hmmmmm in meven as i remember You must type command at last place so yours flag should go bevore command it's related to

Comment: I didn't get you..

Comment: _You must specify a valid li
fecycle phase or a goal in the format_

Means :  **–-DskipTests=true** is not an GOAL( meven's command) for maven It's a FLAG and you should put FLAG BEFORE goal  :)

Comment: but this command is given on the AWS Device Farm documentation and I am following the same procedure

Comment: So You can  arguing more : check mvn man page :
'mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]' 
And the error msg : _Unknown lifecycle phase "?-DskipTests=true"_

Comment: If you are working from a Mac the command would have -DskipTests=true rather than a double "--". I have noted this down as an improvement to the documentation based on platform. Please let us know if you are still seeing the issues.

Comment: Further i am getting an error saying "[ERROR] Failed to parse plugin descriptor for net.masterthought:cucumber-reporti
ng:0.1.0 (C:\Users\Girish\.m2\repository\net\masterthought\cucumber-reporting\0.
1.0\cucumber-reporting-0.1.0.jar): No plugin descriptor found at META-INF/maven/
plugin.xml -> [Help 1]"

Comment: If you're typing exactly what you've typed above, note that you're not really using a double minus/hyphen "--". You're using a dash followed by a minus/hyphen "–-". I'm using a Mac, and lost a bunch of time because I mistook a dash for a hyphen. Look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you type in:

```
mvn -h
```

You'll get the help page for Maven printed out into the console. There you'll see it says:

```
usage: mvn [options] [<goal(s)>] [<phase(s)>]
```

So simply try this:

```
mvn -DskipTests package
```

That is, forget about the "=true" bit.

**WARNING:** Beware of where you copy and paste from. I copied from a Github README.md file and it lost me an hour. There are some typo's out there so subtle they can barely be seen.

This, with a minus/hyphen "-" symbol (ASCII code 45), will work:

```
mvn -DskipTests package
```

This, with a dash "–" (ASCII code 150), will not work:

```
mvn –DskipTests package
```

So if you've been pasting into the command line and you keep getting the *Unknown lifecycle phase "–DskipTests"* error regardless of what you try, just type it in to make sure you use the minus/hyphen character.

Answer (score 0):

mvn plugin-prefix:goal or plugin-group-id:plugin-artifact-id:plugin-version:goal

The above should be available i your POM.xml file
eg:

```
--------------
     <groupId>com.aws.appium</groupId>
         <artifactId>appium-android-test</artifactId>
         <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

 -------------

             <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>test-jar</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the maven dependencies should be included in pom.xml.

Please refer: [AWS Device Farm Setup](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-junit.html)

Then go to your project folder where your pom.xml is present and enter following command in terminal:

**mvn clean package -DskipTests=true**

that's it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying goal for maven build.

In your run configuration for maven build like clear, compile, install, package.

Please following below step to resolve it.

```
right click on your project.
click 'Run as' and select 'Maven Build'
edit Configuration window will open. write any goal but your problem specific write 'package' in Goal text box.
click on 'Run'
```